# Elasticsearch: Filter using word combination, along with AND

Tags: elasticsearch

How do I select for the following documents:

- Must have the word combination "ice cream" (in title or content)
- AND must have the word "chocolate" (in title or content)

**"ice cream" AND chocolate** (in title or content field)

If the words "ice" and "cream" appear, but not as "ice cream" then the document shouldn't be returned.

Coming from MySQL with its nice parenthesis, I'm not finding this intuitive.

```
"must": [
        {
            "multi_match": {
                "query": "'ice cream' chocolate",
                "fields": [
                    "title",
                    "content"
                ]
            },
        }
    ],
```

Example

Document 1:

- Title: Ice cream
- Content: Great with chocolate.

Document 2:

- Title: Milk shake.
- Content: Made with cream, ice, and chocolate.

Document 3:

- Title: Cake
- Content: Super delicious.
- Notes: Try it with chocolate and ice cream.

It should find Document 1, but not Document 2 or 3.

Comment: Could you share the mapping and/or any sample document. That'd be useful.

Comment: I added in a document example

Comment: Upvoted! And, thank you!

Comment: @user984003 thanks and glad you solved issue

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, I used same sample docs and created sample minimum sample mapping to reproduce and try your issue.

**I used nested bool query with [match phrase query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase.html) to solve your issue as your require `ice cream` as a phrase, otherwise it would hv been very easy problem.**

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "title": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "content": {
                "type": "text"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**And search query**

```
{
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "must": [
            {
               "bool": {
                  "should": [
                     {
                        "match_phrase": {
                           "title": "ice cream"
                        }
                     },
                     {
                        "match_phrase": {
                           "content": "ice cream"
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }
            },
            {
               "bool": {
                  "should": [
                     {
                        "match": {
                           "title": "chocolate"
                        }
                     },
                     {
                        "match": {
                           "content": "chocolate"
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

This fetches first doc only as shown below:

```
"hits": [
         {
            "_index": "phrasematch",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 2.3210695,
            "_source": {
               "title": "Ice cream",
               "content": "Great with chocolate"
            }
         }
      ]
```